# Make a list out of two (or more) lists which refers to the original lists when appending new element

Tags: python, class, reference

I would like to create a list of objects which stands for the whole category of objects with the same attribute (let's say the objects that are visible). But once I append the object to one of the subgroups it doesn't update the list of all visible objects (visible_objects). This is known Python behaviour to me but I would like to know what is the best practice to implement this so it appends the element also to the combined list (visible_objects) in a clean and seamless way. (i.e. everytime I append new element to one of the subgroups)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i=i
           
images=[A(1),A(2),A(3)]
images2=[A(4),A(5)]

visible_objects=images+images2

images.append(A(6))

print([x.i for x in images])
print([x.i for x in images2])
print([x.i for x in visible_objects])

[1, 2, 3, 6]
[4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want the last list also contain 6 without reassigning visible_objects after every append. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since the two objects are independent, you have to update both of them.  What are you expecting?  Magic set union?

Comment: Kind of, I would like to have the resulting list basically consisting of references to the original lists. Is this possible? I could imagine doing some magic with pointers if it wasn't Python.

Comment: Not quite: you're still asking for a magic operation to detect when the contents of an object have changed.  The best you can do is to wrap the two updates into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I kind of solved it but I'm not sure it is the best approach.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.i=i
           
class MagicList:
    def __init__(self,elements=[],referenced_lists=None):
        self.elements=elements
        self.referenced_lists=referenced_lists
        self.embedded_in_lists=[]
        if self.referenced_lists is not None:
            self.elements=[]
            for i,magic_list in enumerate(self.referenced_lists):
                for item in magic_list.elements:
                    self.elements.append(item)
                self.referenced_lists[i].embedded_in_lists.append(self)
                                
    def append(self,obj):
        self.elements.append(obj)
        for i,list1 in enumerate(self.embedded_in_lists):
           
            self.embedded_in_lists[i].elements=[]
            for j in range(len(list1.referenced_lists)):
                self.embedded_in_lists[i].elements+=list1.referenced_lists[j].elements
        
    def pop(self,index):
        self.elements.pop(index)
        for i,item in enumerate(self.embedded_in_lists):
            item.elements.pop(index)
              
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.elements))
   
        
m=MagicList([1,3,4])
m2=MagicList([2,5,8]) 
m3=MagicList(referenced_lists=[m,m2])

print(m)
print(m2)
print(m3) 
    
images=MagicList([A(1),A(2),A(3)])
images2=MagicList([A(4),A(5)])

visible_objects=MagicList(referenced_lists=[images,images2])

print([x.i for x in images.elements])
print([x.i for x in visible_objects.elements])

images.append(A(6))

print([x.i for x in images.elements])
print([x.i for x in visible_objects.elements])

images.pop(3)

print([x.i for x in images.elements])
print([x.i for x in visible_objects.elements])
```

Result:

```
    [1, 3, 4]
    [2, 5, 8]
    [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 8]
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    [1, 2, 3, 6]
    [1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5]
    [1, 2, 3]
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337860/843953) is a good approach, but you could also do this by defining a `__getitem__()` in `MagicList` that returns the correct element. This way, you don't need to spend time cloning or copying elements from each list to a big "super-list", and modifications to the "sub-lists" are seamlessly reflected when you try to get an index of the `MagicList` object.

```
class MagicList():
    def __init__(self, *referenced_lists):
        self.lists = referenced_lists
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        cum_len = 0
        for sublist in self.lists:
            sublist_start_index = cum_len
            sublist_end_index = cum_len + len(sublist)
            if sublist_end_index > index:
                return sublist[index - sublist_start_index]
            cum_len = sublist_end_index
        raise IndexError("list index out of range")

    def __str__(self):
        return str([x for x in self])

    def add_list(self, new_list):
        if isinstance(new_list, list): # If new_list is a list, append it to self.lists
            self.lists.append(new_list)
        else: # Try to convert new_list to a list and append that
            try:
                self.lists.append(list(new_list))
            except TypeError: # new_list is not an iterable, so list(new_list) throws a TypeError
                self.lists.append([new_list])
```

Then, you can do:

```
l1  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

m = MagicList(l1, l2) # You can give this any number of lists

print("Original list: ")
print(m)

l1.append(-1)
print("Appending to l1: ")
print(m)

l2.append(1000)
print("Appending to l2: ")
print(m)

l1[0] = 'abc'
print("Modifying l1: ")
print(m)

l2[-2] = 'def'
print("Modifying l2: ")
print(m)

del l1[0]
print("Removing from l1: ")
print(m)

del l2[-1]
print("Removing from l2: ")
print(m)
```

This gives the output:

```
Original list: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
Appending to l1: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
Appending to l2: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000]
Modifying l1: 
['abc', 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000]
Modifying l2: 
['abc', 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 'def', 1000]
Removing from l1: 
[2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 'def', 1000]
Removing from l2: 
[2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 'def']
```

Something to remember though: if you want to append / insert anything to `MagicList` that isn't in the referenced lists, you need to wrap that in a list.